# Использование функции mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

Часто встречается запись такого типа:

```
while($x = mysql_fetch_array($z)){}
```

Скажите пожалуйста, что присваивается `$x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x присваивается строка из выборки БД, выведенная в виде массива. На каждой итерации - следующая.

Пример:

| id | name | info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | teacher |
| 2 | bill | programmer |
| 3 | hank | bomzh |

1. `$x = array('1','id'=>'1','john','name'=>'john','teacher','info'=>'teacher');`
2. `$x = array('2','id'=>'2','bill','name'=>'bill','programmer','info'=>'programmer');`
3. `$x = array('3','id'=>'3','hank','name'=>'hank','bomzh','info'=>'bomzh');`

Чтобы избежать разных индексов массива с одинаковыми значениями, надо выбрать какой-то тип индексов.

```
$type = MYSQL_BOTH // оба типа в одном массиве. По-умолчанию  
$type = MYSQL_ASSOC // ассоциативный массив. Ключи равны названию столбцов  
$type = MYSQL_NUM // числовой массив. Ключи равны порядковому номеру столбца, начиная с 0

mysql_fetch_array($z,$type);
```

Answer (score 1):

Присваивается следующий полученный результат (ряд) от mysql

```
$resource = mysql_query('SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `table` WHERE id>0;');
while ($x = mysql_fetch_array($resource)) {
  echo 'ID = '.$x['id'].'<br />';
  echo 'NAME = '.$x['name'].'<br />';
  echo '<br />';
  }
```

Comment: Подлянка в том, что по-умолчанию там двойной массив.

Comment: Ну эээ да, я в курсе) По-моему, NUM редко пользуются, очень, на моем опыте только в ShopScriptFree видел и готов был убить)) Я в 99% случаев object'ом пользуюсь.